# How to get a parent class, if the parent class is an inherited class?

Tags: c#, .net

So lets say I have this:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemID;
    public List<Enchantment> Enchantments; //Enchantment is a class
}

public class Stick: Item
{
    public int Damage = 18;
    public Stick()
    {
        ItemID = 4;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        foreach (Enchantment ItemEnchantment in Enchantments)
        {
            Enchantment.Update();
        }
    }
}

public class Enchantment
{
    public int EnchantmentID;

    public void Update()
    {
        //NEED HELP HERE

        Parent.Damage += 2; //How do I know my parent is a (Stick)?
                        //I thought of giving each item a uniqueID, and two items cannot have the same id, so the enchantment checks the items list for a specific id, and then uses that as the parent class.
                        //But is there a more efficient way?

    }
}
```

**How do I know my parent is a (Stick)?
I thought of giving each item a uniqueID, and two items cannot have the same id, so the enchantment checks the items list for a specific id, and then uses that as the parent class.
But is there a more efficient way?**

^ considered showing effort O.o ? i just need a more efficient way to accomplish this..

Comment: What do you mean by "Parent"? I don't see a "Parent" in your code.

Comment: @John Oh thanks for that.
 the parent is the stick(parent of the enchantment, of the list), but i want to get the ITEM that owns the ENCHANTMENT

Comment: @COLD Parent is a stick, but its also an item.

Comment: Make sure your implementation properly handles the case where a user has both a +2 and an ×2 enchantment.  Specifically enchantment order should not impact enchantment effect.  One solution I've seen for this is to have a `BaseDamage` member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a parent class. Your `Stick` is **composed** of `Enchantments`.

Easy route: Pass the `Stick` along with the method:

```
// in Stick
foreach (Enchantment ItemEnchantment in Enchantments) {
    ItemEnchantment.Update(this);
}

// in Enchantment..
public void Update(Stick stick) {
    stick.Damage += 2;
}
```

To make it more generic, consider having another class that implements the `Damage` modifier:

```
public class ItemWithDamageModifier : Item {
    public int Damage { get; set; }
}
```

Then inherit from this:

```
public class Stick: ItemWithDamageModifier {
```

Then you can instead use my above method, like this:

```
public void Update(ItemWithDamageModifier damageItem) {
    damageItem.Damage += 2;
}
```

Then you can pass in anything that inherits `ItemWithDamageModifier`, such as a `Stick`, or `Staff`, or `Gun`, etc.

Comment: this seems smart, but for the enchantment i dont know if the item is a stick. how can I know?
Maybe I can assign each stick an id, and convert that id to an item?
 such as: stick is 1, sword is 2, shield is 3... then i convert the id of the item to the inherited item?

Comment: In your example, it **must** be a `Stick` to increase the `Damage`, since `Damage` is a member of `Stick`. You could move `Damage` into the base class `Item`.. but, do all `Item`'s have a `Damage` modifier?

Comment: @user2066764 - The code you posted doesn't tell us where and how you defined Parent.

Comment: Hmm forget that, I'll go with the design of the stick controlling the damage, not the enchantment. Thanks

Comment: Yes! This seems logical.
I'll start separating the items into groups like this.
A few hundred items to go..
Thx

Answer (score 6):

I would make a suggestion more radical than either of the two proposed answers (which are both reasonable). I would take a step back and ask the question "who is in charge here?" That is, what bit of code actually represents the rules of the game?

The path you're going down here is to put the rules of the game into each object; the object computes its own damage. But now some other bit of code is going to have to take into account what happens if the monster resists the enchantment, or is armored, or whatever.

The approach I prefer in these situation is to make a bunch of Rules objects that *actually encode the rules of the game*. That way there is a clear responsibility; Items are responsible for telling the rules engine what Enchantments they have, and the rules engine works out what happens. I think if you choose this approach you'll find that a lot of your problems go away.

Comment: Hmm, this gave me a few ideas. :)

Answer (score 0):

`Enchantment` should not know anything about the `Item` class otherwise it smells like a very bad design. You'd better have smth like this:

```
public class Enchantment
{
    public int EnchantmentID;
    //a property, that contains the damage given by the Enchantment
    //so, when constructing an Enchantment 
    //you should set it to some certain value
    public int Damage { get; set; }
}
```

No need for `Update` method in any of the classes at all, but instead:

```
    int BaseDamage = 18; //a base damage of the item
    //the fact damage, i.e. sum of the base one and all the enchantments
    public int Damage    
    {
        get
        {
            int encDamage = 0;
            if (Enchantments.Any())
                encDamage += Enchantments.Sum(e => e.Damage);
            return BaseDamage + encDamage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yea, I'm going to do this design.